# Minimize function in SciPy optimization difficulty in convergence

Tags: optimization, scipy, minimize, convergence

I'm trying to minimize multivariate function with SciPy optimization minimize function.
The code I'm using to call the function:

```
res = minimize(self.score_gradient, self.initialized_theta, (x,y),'newton-cg', jac = True, tol = 1e-6, options = {'maxiter':100 ,'disp':True })
```

`score_gradient` calculates the score and the jacobian/gradient. The jacobian/gradient was checked numerically. The score printed in command line after calculation, and I see the following in command line:

```
3.3275625564
3.34459750933
3.32755781796
3.34459750933
3.32755307725
3.34459750933
3.32754833425
3.34459750933
3.32754358897
3.34459750933
3.32753884139
3.34459750933
3.3275340915
3.34459750933
3.32752933931
3.34459750933
```

As you can see there is one calculation giving the same result and other minimizing the score as expected. But the function stuck in this calculation for more than half a day, while in MATLAB this calculation takes no more than couple of hours. I know that MATLAB was probably using different optimization algorithm.
Somebody saw this behavior and can point what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Using ``jac=True``, your function ``score_gradient`` needs to return the jacobian too; so with only the command and the "result", it's really quite difficult to tell you what's going wrong among all those things, unless someone experienced the exact same problem... Adding a minimal working example with your function and initialization would help us help you...

Comment: As i said in the post `score_gradient` calculates the jacobian, and i checked it numerically. I think this behavior caused only by `newton-cg` algorithm because i have not see same behavior with `cg` algorithm

Comment: I'm currently having a similar problem to yours. Did you find out what was the problem?

Comment: Sorry can not really remember or find the project